# Mapreduce XML input format - to build custom format

Tags: hadoop, xml-parsing, mapreduce

If the input files in XML format, I shouldn't be using TextInputFormat because TextInputFormat assumes each record is in each line of the input file and the Mapper class is called for each line to get a Key Value pair for that record/line.

So I think we need a custom input format to scan the XML datasets.

Being new to Hadoop mapreduce, is there any article/link/video that shows the steps to build a custom input format?

thanks
nath

Comment: was my answer below useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem***
Working on a single XML file in parallel in MapReduce is tricky because XML does not contain a synchronization marker in its data format. Therefore, how do we work with a file format that’s not inherently splittable like XML?

[***Solution***
MapReduce doesn’t contain built-in support for XML, so we have to turn to another Apache project, Mahout, a machine learning system, which provides an XML InputFormat.](https://dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice)

So I mean no need to have custom input format since Mahout library present.
I am not sure, whether you are going to read or write but both were described in above link.

Pls have a look at [XmlInputFormat implementation details here.](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java)

Furthermore, `XmlInputFormat extends TextInputFormat`