# Parsing XML files using Hadoop

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Java application which parses ~8M files. In order to speed up the parsing, the application is created as multithreaded. Each file is parsed in a thread.
Now I need to run it on Apache Hadoop with two Spark server nodes.
what is the best practice to do that?
- Get rid of the threads and convert the thread-based processing into Map Reduce
- Keep the thread-based processing but implement the Map Reduce inside each thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848347/mapreduce-xml-input-format-to-build-custom-format

Comment: There should only be one Spark server. Did you mean worker/executor nodes? And Spark is different than "Hadoop MapReduce"

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes, I mean Spark workers.  However, let's skip the MapReduce part, can I convert the multithreaded file processing into Spark processing?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you'll need a Hadoop input format for parsing XML files that'll recognize namespaces and determine the outermost tags. The default behavior of Spark textFile method is line by line

Comment: Or you can spend a little more time trying to search Google before coming to Stackoverflow  https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: But this links shows how to do the parser in Spark, which is good and it will be executed in a single Spark worker. What bout making use of the other workers? I guess I need to do it in MapReduce form. Right?

Comment: I think you'll need a better understanding of your terminology. "MapReduce form" isn't a term... And what gave you the impression that only one worker will process files?

Comment: OK..without implementing a MapReduce function, how should the tasks be disturbed along all the workers?

Comment: Because that's how Spark works...? Hadoop MapReduce is different than Spark

Comment: sorry...I think I misunderstood how spark works. So in order to get jobs disturbed along all workers, what should I do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142301/discussion-between-fattah-safa-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Try installing a small Spark cluster, please and simply submit the code for that `spark-xml` package. You don't need to worry yourself about **how** or **where** Spark distributes a process (at least until you hit hardware resource issues, but that isn't Spark related).

Comment: You're right! .. thanks